# Configuring logback.xml to output all log messages in one file or in separate file for each test, based on the Test configuration

Tags: java, logging, junit, logback

I have five JUnit Tests to be run in a loop. (Aware of JUnit parameterization but not using it for now)

What I want is, before running the Tests, it checks the configuration file where there is an option to have `separeLogFile=true/false`. If the option is true, the Test should generate separate log file for each Test, and if the option is false it will generate just one log file for all five Tests.

I am using `logback.xml` and SL4J logger for logging. Currently it generates just one log file for all Tests.

I am confused how do I programmatically specify which/where should the log file generated depending on the option ? Is there any way I can specify two file names and locations and make `logback.xml` choose from them depending on the option in configuration file? I have used `logback.xml` for the first time.

Currently my `logback.xml` looks like following:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<appender name="FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- Daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>target/logs/Log_Test_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>

        <!-- Keep 7 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Configure so that it outputs to both console and log file -->
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Logback's [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/access/sift/SiftingAppender.html) to direct logs to specific log files.

Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SIFTER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>testName</key>
            <defaultValue>ALL</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${testName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>target/logs/Log_Test_${testName}.log</file>

                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                    </pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SIFTER"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

With this Logback configuration the following code ...

```
String[] testNames = new String[] { "one", "two"};

for (String testName : testNames) {
    MDC.put("testName", testName);
    logger.info("This message should go into the log file for {}", testName);
}
```

... will cause **two** log files to be populated:

```
~/dev/code/stackoverflow/target/logs$ cat Log_Test_one.log 
09:04:19.922 [main] INFO  SomeClassTest - This message should go into the log file for one
~/dev/code/stackoverflow/target/logs$ cat Log_Test_two.log 
09:04:19.938 [main] INFO  SomeClassTest - This message should go into the log file for two
```

And the following code ...

```
String[] testNames = new String[] { "one", "two"};

for (String testName : testNames) {
    logger.info("This message should go into the log file for {}", testName);
}
```

... will cause **one** log file to be populated:

```
~/dev/code/stackoverflow/target/logs$ cat Log_Test_ALL.log 
09:06:54.009 [main] INFO  SomeClassTest - This message should go into the log file for one
09:06:54.022 [main] INFO  SomeClassTest - This message should go into the log file for two
```

So, if you populate the `testName` MDC attribute before invoking `logger.xxx()` then the log events wil be sifted i.e. directed to a log file which is named for that MDC value. If you do not populate the `testName` MDC attribute then all log events will be directed to an 'ALL' log file.

**Update 1** in response to this comment:

> well I replcaed whole block of my original File Appender with the one you provided, but it is not producing log file at all..Something is going wrong.

It's difficult to diagnose what's going wrong without seeing all of your configuration so I have updated this answer to include a complete `logback.xml` and this configuration has debug enabled so you should see output like ...

```
09:59:32,268 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SIFTER]
09:59:32,281 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator] for [discriminator] property
09:59:32,298 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
09:59:32,298 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
09:59:32,304 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SIFTER] to Logger[ROOT]
...
09:59:34,725 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
09:59:34,730 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE-one]
...
09:59:34,732 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE-one] - File property is set to [target/logs/Log_Test_one.log]
```

... which shows the sifting appender in action.

Comment: Thanks glitch. This could be exactly what I am looking for. When I write this SIFTER appender, shall I remove File Appender ? if not then how exactly can I write both at the same time ? I wrote both and it did not work !

Comment: The SiftingAppender **wraps** the FileAppender, so you do not need a separate FileAppender. You could use the example I provided; it works _as is_. I'd suggest starting with my example and once you have it working then change the FileAppender within the SiftingAppender as you see fit.

Comment: well I replcaed whole block of my original File Appender with the one you provided, but it is not producing log file at all..Something is going wrong.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a complete logback.xml, please try it and read the last section of the answer - where it descrbes Logback's debug output - too.

Comment: Glitch, I found out that it always takes Key's defaultValu and not from the variable TestName for e.g. so MDC.put("tesName", Integer.toString(test)); is not working. test is an integer for me and therefore converting it to a string..

Comment: Is this a typo: `MDC.put("tesName", Integer.toString(test));`? The correct MDC attribute name is: **testName** not **tesName** ...

Comment: I don't know what else to say then. I don't have enough of your code to diagnose this issue. The simple example I provided works _as is_. I'd suggest either debugging Logback to understand where your implementation has gone wrong or strip everything back to the simplest possible example (e.g. the code and config that I provided) and when you have that working start adding in whatever you need to get back to your own implementaiton.